# Best practise to write a boolean API in Java Sturts 2 server?

Tags: java, api, http, server

I need to write an API to check if a user name already exists in a database.
I want my server (Struts Action class instance in tomcat server) to return `true`/`false`.

Its something like this

```
checkUserName?userName=john
```

I want  to know what is the standard way to do this?
Shall I return a JSON response with just one `boolean` value ... seems like a overkill.

Shall I do something like manually setting the HTTP header to 200 or 404 (for `true`/`false`), but that seems to violate the actual purpose of using the headers which I believe must only be used to indicate network failures etc.

Comment: It doesn't matter what you return from the server, but how you do it. Post your code.

Answer (score 3):

(Too long for a comment.)

I don't see any reason *not* to return a standard JSON response with something indicating whether or not the user name exists. That's what APIs do: there's nothing "overkill" about providing a response useful across clients.

To your second point: headers do a *lot* more than "indicate network problems". A 404 isn't a network problem, it means the requested resource doesn't exist. It is *not* appropriate in your case, because you're not requesting a resource: the *resource* is `checkUserName`, which *does* exist. If instead your request was `/userByName/john` a 404 would be appropriate if the user didn't exist. That's not an appropriate request in this case, because you don't want to return the user.

A 401 isn't a network problem, it's an authentication issue. A 302 isn't a network problem, it's a redirect. Etc. Using HTTP response codes is *entirely* appropriate, *if* they match your requests.

Comment: Is there some header for the true /false use case

Comment: @SainathS.R A general HTTP "true" or "false" makes no sense from a query, and there's no way it could be applied in a general way. A 302 (mis-implemented across most browsers) *might* make sense, but don't do that. As stated in the answer, IMO a 404 is inappropriate since you're hitting a search endpoint, not a resource. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: OK I'll go with the Json then